# How to make a "webhook"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webhooks

I need the "WinForm" application for correspondence in viber.
 "Webhook" is planned to receive data (events) from viber, then the data will be used in the application "WinForm".

I did:

1. created the project "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)";
2. chose a template - "Empty" + "MVC" + "API";
3. added controller "Controller MVC 5 - empty". Controller name "HookController";
4. I run the application "Postman";
5. "Postman". I set the request "POST";
6. "Postman". I set the link `http://localhost:44836/Hook`;
7. "Postman". Click "SEND";
8. The result, see the picture "- = RESULT = -";

If I understand the theory correctly, then after performing the `"Postman" action. I click "SEND"`, the `ViberProcess (HttpContext context)` method should be executed in the `HookController.cs` controller and the code should stop at the `breakpoint`.
This is not happening.

Documentation `Viber REST API` - [link](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/)

**Question.**
How to make a Webhook?

**Code `HookController.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

//
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;

namespace WebAppl1.Controllers
{
    public class HookController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Hook
        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

         [HttpPost]
        // [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void ViberProcess(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream s = context.Request.InputStream;
                // Stream s = Context.Request.InputStream;
                // or  Stream s  =  HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
                s.Position = 0;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
                string jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // Other code that converts json text to classes
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // .....
            }
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

`7. "Postman". Click "SEND";`
[image]

`8. The result, see the picture "- = RESULT = -";`
[image]

`Server error in application '/'.
Could not find this resource.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource (or one of its dependencies) may have been deleted, received a different name, or may be temporarily unavailable. Review the following URL and verify that it is correct.
Requested URL: / Hook
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319; ASP.NET version: 4.7.3062.0`

**Update_1**
**I use the link `http://localhost:44836/api/Hook`**
The code does not stop at `breakpoint`.
Result:
`{

"Message": "Could not find the HTTP resource corresponding to the request URI \" http://localhost:44836/api/Hook\ ".", 
"MessageDetail": "Could not find the type corresponding to the controller \" Hook \ " . "
}`

**I use the link `http://localhost:44836/Hook/ViberProcess`**
The code does not stop at `breakpoint`.
Result
`Server error in application '/'.
For this object, no parameterless constructors are defined.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
Examine the stack trace for more information about this error and the code snippet that caused it.
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameter-less constructors are defined for this object.
Source Error:
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
Information on the origin and location of the exception can be obtained using the following exception stack trace.`

[image]

Comment: What about `http://localhost:44836/Hook/ViberProcess`?

Comment: Asp.net does not care about the name of controller action if it already has [Post] attribute.

Comment: @korulis Doesn't that depend on if OP is using the default routing, or their own routing rules?

Comment: @korulis there are two types of controllers. API and MVC - you are talking about API controller but OP is using MVC controller - and that is also the answer

Comment: @john Updated the question. See "Update_1"

Comment: maybe because you have not passed the context in the body as the POST method.

Comment: @ChandreshKhambhayata Is it not difficult for you to supplement your answer?
  Write a few steps what I have to do.
What should the method look like?

I'm still learning. I have already read a lot of information. I have already mixed everything in my head.
Thank.

Comment: @eusataf you are using **MVC controller**. Just leave server side mention parameter empty. Get from `HttpContext`. Using I use the link `http://localhost:44836/Hook/ViberProcess` I have ref for [link](https://codeburst.io/what-are-webhooks-b04ec2bf9ca2#a2ea) and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `HttpContext context` in your `ViberProcess` action.

So, the method will become

```
public IActionResult ViberProcess()
{
    Stream s = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;

    //... continue your code from here.
}
```

The reason behind this is, You have mention `HttpContext context` as an Argument of `ViberProcess` but while you are sending request it will search with the Exact schema.

So, in your request, you can not pass the `HttpContext` from anywhere. So, this request will never be found.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Code]

Try this an let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: How to arrange the string `Stream s = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;`?
Picture - [link] (https://imageshost.ru/images/2019/07/02/00.png)

Comment: this is the different question, hope my solution has resolved your main issue, just comment that code and check whether it is working or now

Comment: Also, you need to inherit ApiController and not the Controller, if you are working on the .Net Framework based project.

Comment: I get the error: `"Could not find the type or name of the namespace" IActionResult "
(perhaps a missing using directive or an assembly reference)."`
`IActionResult` or `ActionResult`? In other words, `ActionResult` without `I`.
And yet, if it is not difficult for you, how to properly arrange the string `Stream s = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;`?

Comment: What link to use in "Postman" for "POST" request?
`http://localhost:44836 /`
or `http://localhost:44836/Hook/`
or `http://localhost:44836/Hook/ViberProcess`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195855/discussion-between-chandresh-khambhayata-and-eusataf).